# Sapply: the character of standard deviation in R

Tags: r

I am using sapply to calculate the estimators of S.D. for the Bernoulli variable.
Here is a portion of data

```
df <- read.table (text=" speed time
0   1
0   1
1   0
1   0
1   1

", header=TRUE)
```

The following code does not give the estimator of S.D. for the Bernoulli variable

```
sapply(df, sd)
```

The expected estimators of S.D are :

```
speed           time
0.489897949 0.489897949
```

Is there another character for the sd?

Answer (score 0):

`sd` calculates the *sample* standard deviation.  If you want the *population* standard deviation you need to multiply by the factor shown. (Which one you should be using is another matter -- usually the sample standard deviation is more appropriate.)

```
n <- nrow(df)
sqrt((n-1)/n) * sapply(df, sd)
##     speed      time 
## 0.4898979 0.4898979
```

or calculate it yourself

```
sd_pop <- function(x) sqrt(mean((x - mean(x))^2))
sapply(df, sd_pop)
##     speed      time 
## 0.4898979 0.4898979
```

or if what you wanted was to calculate the standard deviation for the binomial distribution:

```
sd_b <- function(x, p = mean(x)) sqrt(p * (1-p))
sapply(df, sd_b)
##     speed      time 
## 0.4898979 0.4898979
```

Comment: We do not have a character like "sd" for the Bernoulli variable, I mean sqrt(pq)?

Comment: Sorry, I meant like this, sapply(df, a character instead of sd). I do not want to code the formula